# How to push text to the right of the page?

Tags: formatting, cv

I'm writing a resume, and I want to put the city and year on the right side of the page after I type the company name. For example:

Company X ____________________________________________________ City, State

But without the underscore. How can I force part of that text to the right side of the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example, you could use `\hfill` before the words you want on the right:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Company X \hfill City, State

\end{document}
```